# Remove from launcher BUT keep enabled / startable

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

i tried coding it, i tried solving it with google and stackoverflow, nothing found :=) so hopefully someone else has a better idea, im not sure if i get everything right:

i have 2 applications: ad (main app) / adfree-pro (just license starts ad app without ads ;P)

so **the problem is, i want to have a pro version (with pro icon) in the launcher, which starts the normal-ad app, which is (the normal ad-app) not in the launcher.**

i tried removing the ad-app from the launcher (which due to my research should JUST remove it from the launcher)

> pkgMgr.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_NAME + ".Main"),
>                               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

which results to: the icons in the launcher are correct ;) **BUT** the application can't be found on the phone, launched, started, even not with a launcher pro activity shortcut. it seems to be there (shortcuts can be created) but i crashes with an activity exception when i try to launch it.

> 02-18 14:38:59.237: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9941): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

which doesnt seem to belong (the error message)
it looks like there has happened more to the application than just simply removed the entry in the launcher.

thanks a lot guys,
every workaround for this situation appreciated :)
best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have app installed and hide it's launcher icon. The way I'm addressing it with my application which works similar to yours that I don't try to fight icons but instead the app can be launched using ether icon. Obviously you don't have to do in the main (free) app and the code that launches app from your pro icon will look something like the following:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    // check if main app is installed. If yes then start it
    if (appExists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Started main app from Pro");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("myapp://com.myapp.main"));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        // display view with link back to Market 
        onAppNotExists();
    }
}
```

It's up to you to implement `appExists()` which is probably some sort of license check

Of course, alternatively you can develop your app's common code as [library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) and then distribute it in 2 flavors without duplicating the code

Comment: thanks for confirming my thoughts. until now i've hidden the pro icon, which works perfectly, launcher just shows 1 icon, but now i wanted to show the users that they're using (and makeing them aware of the benefit ;)) the pro version, so it seems, to give them the possibility to use a seperate pro icon, 2 icons are un-avoidable.

for all others: summary: hide license app works ;)
hide main app. doesnt. 

thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

> BUT the **application** can't be found on the phone, launched, started,
>   even not with a launcher pro activity shortcut.

Not application, but activity. 


So, if your `LAUNCHER` activity is `BaseActivity`, you may create something like `BaseFakeActivity` (don't forget to set it as `LAUNCHER` in your manifest instead of your `BaseActivity`) and which only function is to start your `BaseActivity` and then `finish()` itself.


 Now you may hide your `BaseFakeActivity` but you'll still be possible to interact with your `BaseActivity`.


 P.S.: Don't forget to test your app's behaviour after doing things this way ;)

Comment: hey man, thanks a lot,.. that sounds great.. doing some refactoring right now.. sounds like a perfect plan, will give u some feedback and accept your answer when I'm ready :) planned for tonight... :)